# Why does dart ask me to declare an unnecessary argument?

Tags: flutter, dart, casting

Why do I need to declare a variable of type int called "idx" if it does not serve any purpose in the generate funciton below?

```
Random r2 = new Random();
  var list = List<int>.generate(5, (int idx) => r2.nextInt(100));
```

If I do not declare it dart gives me the following error

```
The argument type 'int Function()' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int Function(int)'
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`List.generate`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/List/List.generate.html) has been defined as

```dart
List.generate(int length, E generator(int index),
      {bool growable = true});
```

So you need to provide a function to use `List.generate`.

If you like to ignore it you can use `_`.

```dart
 List<int>.generate(5, (_) => r2.nextInt(100));
```

Answer (score 0):

Dart is type-safe, so it expects that the type signatures of arguments match.  You can't pass a `int Function()` where an `int Function(int)` is expected.

*Must* it be that way?  No.  Since the `int` argument is clearly unused, the compiler conceivably could automatically transform `() => r2.nextInt(100)` into `(_) => (() => r2.nextInt(100))()`.  However, doing so might hide mistakes where a wrong function is passed.  Dart often favors being explicit.